# VSTO outlook body text changed event

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm developing VSTO outlook add in. My add-in inserts links into HTMLBody. And if some of this links will be deleted by user, I need to make server request.
So, is there any possibilities to handle text changed event of mail item?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say "HTMLBody"? As I know in body of outlook items we have RTF format. In this case we don't have any ways to subscribe to some events which can indicate us that text in body was changed.

Comment: Outlook.MailItem has BodyFormat property and HtmlBody. So, I'm using HTML body format and add links programmatically to HtmlBody property.

Comment: In this case, you have only one way to validate text, you can subscribe to 'SendItem' event and when it occurs you can get text from body and validate it. If text is not valid you can show message with errors and make 'cancel' flag as a true.

Comment: Yeah, I understood that, but I thought may be there is some event like "textchanged" that I can catch.